# C# file which defines enums for both C# and C++

Tags: c#, c++

I have the following code in cs file (compiled in Visual Srudio)

```
#if __cplusplus
// C++ region, hide the private C# key word "private" from C++
#define private
namespace fastmapping
{
#else
// C# region, namespace and class so the C++ enum would not be the same in C#
namespace Interface
{
    public static class Example
    {
#endif
        // Common part to both C# and C++ (in C++ the private keyword is omitted by define)
        private enum GatedMode
        {
            GATED_MODE,
            NON_GATED_MODE
        };

        // other enums
    }
}
```

How c++ can use this enums? In CLI?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings- the fact that this code is compiled and works (I didn`t write it) just want to understand how does it work

Comment: You would usually use #ifdef __cplusplus or #if defined(__cplusplus in C++ wouldn't you?

Comment: @DaveDoknjas `#if` will have the same effect (undefined macros "default" to zero), and C# doesn't have `#ifdef`, so...

Answer (score 6):

**The "trick" here is that this is not just a C# file.**

It may have a `.cs` extension, but it has been "cleverly" written to be both valid C++ and valid C#, using the `#if` directive (which exists in both languages, but only has `__cplusplus` set in the former) to select which code to run, where the code differs.

So, when you pass it to a C++ compiler, it's C++ source; when you pass it to a C# compiler, it's C# source. It's two source files in one, that happen to list enums with the same members.

There's no actual interop here; just text trickery.

Unfortunately, it's created a big mess, and has undefined behaviour in C++ due to redefining a keyword.

PInvoke is the proper way to bridge C++/CLI and C#.

Comment: thank. I agree with you . but technically I can`t undertsand how compilation/linkage  is performed. This was actually a questiion

Comment: It's not quite clever enough - it doesn't compile in C++ at all.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas It does very, very nearly ;) I think we'll forgive the trailing brace, seeing as the "real" example likely has way more code in it, ending with a proper `#if`-protected brace.

Comment: @Yakov The same way it's ever performed: pass it to a compiler. In this case, twice!

Comment: I totally agree that the original "tricky" code is a complete mess - no one should write code like this.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas No it doesn't. Undefined macros act like `0`, and `#if 0` doesn't pass.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: Yes, of course - I overlooked the fact that "__cplusplus" is predefined in my test project - doh!